# How do I specify the type of the range variable in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

How do I specify the type of the range variable in a linq query?

Comment: For your future reference, this is documented in section 7.15.2.2 "Explicit range variable types".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just declare it with the variable itself:

```
var query = from string text in collection
            where text.Length > 5
            select text.ToUpper();
```

This will translate to:

```
var query = collection.Cast<string>()
                      .Where(text => text.Length > 5)
                      .Select(text => text.ToUpper());
```

Comment: I was trying this on a number collection stored as strings `var numbers = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }` but this LINQ query `numbers.Cast<int>().Where((int i, int index) => index > 2 && i > 3);` throws `InvalidCastException`. string "1" should be convertible to numeric 1. Isn't it? If this is not working then where would this Cast operator really be useful in LINQ queries?

Comment: @RBT: No, you can't cast from a string to an int. You want to start with `numbers.Select(text => int.Parse(text))` so that you have an `IEnumerable<int>` to work with. The `Cast` operator is useful where casts are useful in normal code.